# How do bounties on closed questions work?

Tags: discussion, bounties, closed-questions

I answered a question with a bounty and my answer was accepted, but the question was closed (it was flagged as needing to be more focused). What happens to the bounty? I didn't get it, and now there seems to be no trace of it.

Answer in question: [Detecting pattern in OHLC data in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730416/detecting-pattern-in-ohlc-data-in-python/62805962#62805962)

EDIT - This isn't actually a duplicate of the linked question. The referenced question refers to a bounty that was awarded and then lost, while this one refers to a bounty on an accepted answer that was never awarded. Details are however clarified in [How does the bounty system work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), in the section *What happens if a bounty question is closed or deleted?*

It turns out a moderator refunded the bounty and closed the question, and the OP accepted my answer shortly after. The bounty had to be refunded to close the question. Since the bounty had already been refunded and the question closed, the bounty was not awarded.

Comment: Do you have a link to that question?

Comment: You can't close a bountied question

Comment: You can't add a bounty to closed questions and you can't close a question that has a bounty... so if that's not the case, I... think you might have a bug. A link to the question would be helpful.

Comment: This is answered in our FAQ on bounties, [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), in the section *What happens if a bounty question is closed or deleted?*.

Comment: Looks like a moderator removed the bounty and closed the question in this case. It was refunded to the asker. If they fix the question, they can offer the bounty again.

Comment: I'm guessing it's [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730416/detecting-pattern-in-ohlc-data-in-python). The question you linked has never had a bounty.

Comment: t was a dup, it turns out. And it looks like a moderator refunded the bounty and then closed the question, and after that the OP accepted my answer. Sad day https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730416/detecting-pattern-in-ohlc-data-in-python/62805962#62805962

Comment: @Ollie It's more a case of bounty offerers having too much power, since bounties block closure.